# Looping 24 hour clock time difference

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a time calculator so someone can enter a start time in a textbox and an end time in another textbox in 24 hour time format and it will calculate the difference and show it in a label.

How can I make my code do the same thing but with a loop? I'm just looking to make the code shorter instead of having a block of code for each day of the week, shown below is just the Monday and Tuesday code.

```
//Monday
TimeSpan Mon1In, Mon1Out;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBoxInMon1.Text, out Mon1In))
    Mon1In = default(TimeSpan);
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBoxOutMon1.Text, out Mon1Out))
    Mon1Out = default(TimeSpan);
MonLabel1.Text = (Mon1Out - Mon1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");

//Tuesday
TimeSpan Tues1In, Tues1Out;
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBoxInTues1.Text, out Tues1In))
    Tues1In = default(TimeSpan);
if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(TextBoxOutTues1.Text, out Tues1Out)) 
    Tues1Out = default(TimeSpan);
TuesLabel1.Text = (Tues1Out - Tues1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
```

Comment: Why do you have different code for each day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just make a function. This is called [refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring).

```
private void GetTimeValues(TextBox txtIn, TextBox txtOut, 
    out TimeSpan inTime, out Timespan outTime)
{
    if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(txtIn.Text, out inTime))
        inTime = default(TimeSpan);
    if (!TimeSpan.TryParse(txtOut.Text, out outTime))
        outTime = default(TimeSpan);
}
```

Then call the function and set your label.

```
TimeSpan Mon1In, Mon1Out;
GetTimeValues(TextBoxInMon1, TextBoxOutMon1, out Mon1In, out Mon1Out);
MonLabel1.Text = (Mon1Out - Mon1In).TotalHours.ToString("f2");
```

You should probably use a more descriptive function name, this was just the first thing I thought of.

You could also include the label logic inside the function as well, just thread the information along in the same fashion.